# Exponential powers with range

Tags: python, range, exponent

I'm having a problem with my code

```
def bconver(n,b):
    for i in range(n):
        x = b ** i
```

I am trying to have `b` to the power of all the `i` values from the range of n. I need to be able to take those values and divide them by n allowing me to change it to any base.

I have tried this code but it doesn't work since I can't divide those values after. Also, I need the answers not in a list

```
x = [b ** i for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: no my question is very different, Im only asking how to take all the values of `i ` and put them to the power of b. no base conversion question was asked

Comment: Fair enough, then I did not understand your comment on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide each value in your list comprehension by `n`:

```
x = [b ** i for i in range(n)]  
x_over_n = [a/n for a in x]
```

#### edit:

```
def x_to_the_i_over_n(x, i, n):
    return x**i / n

n = 4
x = 123
results = []
for i in range(n):
    results.append(x_to_the_i_over_n(x, i, n))
```

#### edit 2:

```
import numpy

b = numpy.array(range(10))
b**2
#--> array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])

b**2 / 4
#--> array([  0.  ,   0.25,   1.  ,   2.25,   4.  ,   6.25,   9.  ,  12.25, 16.  ,  20.25])
```

Comment: Oh wow I overlook that thanks you, but I need it without a list

Comment: How exactly do you need it?

Comment: the overall problem I am trying to solve is to change a base 10 number from to any base, without the abc thing. The final answer I need to get is a number not in a list

Comment: I just need to be able to do the exponential notation without a list

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what "without the abc" means?

Comment: Sorry for the clarification issue, the abc thing I am referring to is when people do the base conversion they do x =123456789ABCD, but that was just for info on the whole problem. The question I am trying to ask is how do I do the exponential notation not in a list just to be able to get single integers

Comment: I edited my answer, but I am still rather unclear what exactly you want

Comment: to make it more clear, ignore the base conversion part. what I want is to be able to do this, example (x= for I in range 5) take all these value b^x so 4^1, 4^2, 4^3 and so on without a list, the function takes in only two parameters.

Comment: Still unclear to me... maybe I have a blind spot here. Edited again; is that what you want? (with numpy, you can do all ops at once, but the results are still in an array.

Comment: I am very very sorry, but without any libraries. And ya I can't have an array only integers.

Comment: Can you post the output you need, maybe that would clarify it.

Comment: yes maybe this will help, some pseudocode. the function with two parameters(n,b) if 5 were to be inputted as n. and 14 for b. This would happen, 14^0, 14^1,14^2,14^3,14^4,14^5. the output would be 1 14 196 2744 38416 and 537824 no list and then I can divide those single integers by n if I need

Comment: I see... you can only return one object from a function, I am afraid; in this case, either one integer, or a collection of integers (list, tuple, or other data structure)

Comment: oh ok I see, I don't need those values all printed out  as the goal for me is to have an integer base 10 changed to any base. could you do it so the numbers run through it but the values don't get printed out. I can finish the rest I just need this part.

Comment: I modified the first edit so the results are stored in a list i/o printed. The first list comprehension also works.

Comment: Thanks, can’t beleve a such a high class guy like you answerd my question

Answer (score 1):

You can perform any operations you want inside that list comprehension. For example,

```
x = [(b ** i) / n for i in range(n)]
```

sounds like the final result you're looking for. If you want the intermediate result, just use another list comprehension:

```
x = [b ** i for i in range(n)]
x_divided_by_n = [element / n for element in x]
```

If you want more compact ways to express these kinds of operations, look into using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: How would I go about using modulo for x and n. From the first example you gave

Comment: @nick The standard modulo operator `%` works in Python (`5 % 3 = 2`, for example).

Comment: yes I understand that but after doing x = [(b ** i) / n for i in range(n)] how would I do for example p = n%x

Comment: also im not sure if this changes the code but I need the answer not in a list